# Having trouble loading Unity Xcode onto phone

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I successfully created my first Unity program and successfully built it in Xcode, but it fails to load on my iPhone Xr. It creates the icon, the screen on my phone turns black/brown, then the app fails and I get the following message in Xcode. I tried clean and delete all derive data, but the issue persists. What am I doing wrong?

```
360Project004[633:99382] Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'

    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: stat() failed with errno=3
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'
2020-02-01 01:19:04.463850-0800 360Project004[633:99382] Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D37C95B-6B87-4389-B2EA-8BB6584D3253/360Project004.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue and after going through the forums I came across that at the moment you need the paid Apple developer account and that should do the trick. I am hoping Apple addresses this issue soon.